# How to reduce for loops to make code more efficient?

Tags: c#, for-loop, optimization, coding-efficiency

I am practicing C# and looking for code optimisation techniques. This code is giving the expected output and I want to write a more efficient code.

```
int test(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int p = 1;

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            p = 2 * p;
        }

        p = p + (2 * i * i);
        sum = sum + p;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I think that two for loops can be reduced to one but I can't figure out how to do it. Any advices?

Comment: Have you measured the performance of a release build? It's likely that the compiler will perform better optimisations than you can.

Comment: For raw performance, you could solve the recurrence `s(k) = s(k-1) + 2**k + 2 k**2` and calculate the final `s(n)` without any loops ;-)

Comment: @dxiv Could you make that an answer?  I think future readers could benefit if you outlined the process of turning these loops into an expression.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks! I made it recursive now. I got rid of the outer loop but there isn't a way to get 2**k without using a loop, right?. I am trying to convert my code into pseudo code too.

Comment: @UçanPatateslerinLorduCan The i'th power of 2 can be easily calculated directly as `1 << i`, like shown in the posted answer.

Comment: @user5151179 That would be better explained next door at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/). In the end it resolves to just `int test(int n) { return 2 * ((1 << n) - 1) + n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 3; }`.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks you so much. I think my problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the bit shift left `<<` operator instead of the `j` loop.

```
    int test(int n)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            int p = 1 << i; // <= Here it is

            p += 2 * i * i;
            sum += p;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain or link to a post how does the shift left operator replace (do the job of) the for loop?

Comment: Thank you. I've had never heard of this operator before.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use bit shift you can use Math.Pow. Internally, computationally it is likely to cost same as the for loop you have, and bit shift could be better cost wise. Here is the alternate solution

```
        int test(int n)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                int p = 1;

                p = (int)Math.Pow(2 * p, i);

                p = p + (2 * i * i);
                sum = sum + p;
            }
            return sum;
        }
```